# UIButton in UIView not responding to any events

Tags: ios5, ios6, uiview, uibutton

I'm using the below code to add a `UIButton` to my `UIView`:

```
    rejectButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [rejectButton addTarget:self action:@selector(rejectBuddy:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [rejectButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Heiti SC Medium" size:15]];
    rejectButton.titleLabel.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [rejectButton setTitle:@"Reject" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [rejectButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Logout_Profile.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    rejectButton.frame = CGRectMake(168, 380, 141.0, 45.0);
    rejectButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [mainView addSubview:rejectButton];
```

When I click the button, it's not doing anything. I'm not even seeing the animation that the button was pressed. Is there anything I am missing with this?

It's working when I manually create a `UIButton` on the `UIView` on the storyboard. But for my use case, thats not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to enable highlighting on touch. Make sure your UIView has userInteractionEnabled enabled as well. And you may want to use UIControlEventTouchUp.

```
rejectButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
```

and comment out

```
//rejectButton.titleLabel.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

Got this problem before, and it seems like my animated transitioning is not yet completed. I forgot to to put `completeTransition:Bool` at the end of my  `animateTransition:context` method.